How can I derive mode from a DX cluster spot?
First some background. I am writing some software to control an amateur radio transceiver based on the user's selection of a spot from a DX cluster. My goal is to set the frequency and mode such as LSB, USB, CW, RTTY, DATA, etc.
The pieces of information available from the spot are the call signs of each operator, the frequency, the time and some unstructured comments. Comments do occasionally include the mode but this is not done in a consistent manner, if present at all. Thus it is easy to get the frequency but the challenge is how to infer the mode from this limited data.
My first idea was to use the frequency. I studied the three IARU regional band plans and found they agree pretty well so this looked promising.
But then I realized the IARU Region 2 plan, which includes the US, differs markedly from the FCC mode assignments. This complication suggests it will be necessary to keep different tables of frequency and mode for different locations. (Station location can be inferred by using the cty.dat country file maintained by AD1C)
So my question is: based on the information in a DX cluster spot how might I go about deciding the mode in which the contact was made?
I am well aware that lots of logging programs do this already quite accurately, so I have a feeling I am missing something here.
Thanks for your help.


Thus it is easy to get the frequency but the challenge is how to infer the mode from this limited data.

I'd say, in general you can't. Band plans often just define general usage ("voice", "digital data") and bandwidths, rarely actual modes (I must admit I don't know how it is for the FCC). So, it's convention that could drive your decision here.
However, since you can filter by the mode in the dxspot search, these spots get published with that information present. No need to infer; if you get the spots from dx cluster, you just do separate queries for the different modes they support, and then you know which modes the results have. You can then merge these different results in your client, or leave them separated by mode.
Note that before you "abuse" someone else's website as dataquery API, I'd recommend you contact them, they might be very willing to help you out with giving you info on how to do that. They might ask you to help run their website.

I am well aware that lots of logging programs do this already quite accurately, so I have a feeling I am missing something here.

They have the actual transmission as data foundation. Sure, if you can look at what you receive, you can detect the mode to a certain degree of certainty.
If it's the operator's own contacting, then the operator will probably have set the mode manually.

Thanks for your comments. I do have a good friend who is a sysop for a DX Spider node. He has already shared with me the code it uses to implement mode filters. At least in Spider, each mode is simply mapped to a range of frequencies, nothing more than that. Unfortunately the problem is each mode range is very wide so there is a large amount of overlap. Thus using the mapping to go the other way (from frequency to mode) is pretty much useless. As to your last point, it might very well be this entire exercise is pretty pointless :-)
